# How to make edits work on reacts component library css files?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, antd

I am using some component libraries for a project with react such as `antd, material-ui` etc. I need to modify some components css. For example, I looked up in the directory of `antd` and located the css files under `node_modules\antd\dist`. There are few files along with `antd.css` and `antd.min.css` there is also a file named `antd.less`.
My question is which file do I make the change to css? Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say but probably the antd.less.

I would strongly recommend to overwrite the css in a localcss file instead of modifying node_modules though. Will be more convenient to maintain. It will become a pain in production or if you want to update your modules. Considered bad practice.

And if you do want to edit it directly in the module, clone the module into your rep. Dont leave it in node_modules, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding Less variables (alternative way)#

Override variables via less definition files.

Create a standalone less file like the one below, and import it in your project.

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";   // import official less entry file
@import "your-theme-file.less";   // override variables here
```

Default Variables
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less